# What is the max limit of acceptable characters/words in a confirmation box button?

Tags: buttons, popup, confirmation

For example, if I ask a user

**Would you like to send an email instead of print to save paper?**

- **Yes**, send email and save paper
- **No**, take a print

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the anwser will depend on your context.

In a lot of guidelines, they advice to put a verb or very short sentence (Verb + subject) in confirmation box button.

Would you like to send an email instead of print to save paper?

- Send Email
- Take a print

I advice to read this : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/ControlsButtons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH48-SW1

Especially this paragraph :

> **Use a verb or verb phrase and title-style capitalization for the title of a push button.**
>   The title should describe the action the button performs—Save, Close, Print, Delete, Change Password, and so on. If a push button acts on a single setting or entity, name the button as specifically as possible; “Choose Picture…,” for example, is more helpful than “Choose…” Because buttons initiate an immediate action, there’s no need to include “now” in the button title.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a max-character limit or a `Don't` in terms of how many character should be there on the confirmation box?

Comment: Can you please also share how it will `depend on my context`?

Comment: I think max words would be a more useful question because you may have 1 word but when translated becomes very long in terms of characters - so characters is less important. keep the words to a minimum as per the advice in the answer.

Comment: @DaveHaigh I think characters may also matter since it may decide whether two buttons on a popup will come horizontally adjacent to each other or vertically adjacent to each other.